# If with multiple ands, nested ifs, or ifs with booleans?

Tags: vba, if-statement, boolean

I have tried these multiple ways, and I still am not getting the result I need. I have a UserForm with multiple checkboxes. If two checkboxes are checked, I want one answer, but if the third checkbox is checked, a separate answer. What is the correct way to do this? 
Nested Ifs:

```
Dim Cost As Range, SetUpCost As Range, Prices As Range
Set Cost = WB.Worksheets("Calculations").Range("F42")
Set Prices = WB.Worksheets("Calculations").Range("D42")

If QuarterlyCheck = True And SecurityLite = True Then
If NoSetUpCheck = False Then
    SecurityLitePrice.Caption = "$" & Cost.Value * 4
    SetUpFee.Caption = "$" & SetUpCost.Value
End If
ElseIf NoSetUpCheck = True Then
    SecurityLitePrice.Caption = "$" & Prices.Value * 4
    SetUpFee.Caption = ""
End If
```

Or multiple ifs:

```
If QuarterlyCheck = True And SecurityLite = True And NoSetUpCheck = False Then
    SecurityLitePrice.Caption = "$" & Cost.Value * 4
    SetUpFee.Caption = "$" & SetUpCost.Value
End If
If QuarterlyCheck = True And SecurityLite = True And NoSetUpCheck = True Then
    SecurityLitePrice.Caption = "$" & Prices.Value * 4
    SetUpFee.Caption = ""
End If
```

Neither are getting me the result I need.

Comment: If the third checkbox is checked does that supersede having both checkboxes 1 and 2 checked? So ```1 = True and 2 = True``` or ```1 = False and 2 = False``` is irrelevant if ```3 = true```?

Comment: No, checkbox 1 and 2 have to be checked to coincide with the other relevant subs on the UserForm. Checking 3 (or unchecking), changes the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
If QuarterlyCheck = True And SecurityLite = True Then
    If NoSetUpCheck = True Then
        SecurityLitePrice.Caption = "$" & Prices.Value * 4
        SetUpFee.Caption = ""
    Else 'Means NoSetUpCheck = False
        SecurityLitePrice.Caption = "$" & Cost.Value * 4
        SetUpFee.Caption = "$" & SetUpCost.Value
    End If
Else
    'Whatever else ....
End If
```

Comment: It should technically works with what you asked. What is it exactly that does not work? Is there something more we need to know? Are there any value in both cells D42 and F42?

Comment: Yes, I checked. Perhaps I need to think about restructuring the form.

Comment: You should have a trigger in your Userform to get that code activated? Something like `button_OK_Click()` or `optionSomething_Change_Click()` ….